# grep does not work in Ubuntu 16.04 as usual

Tags: grep

I have realized that grep does not work as usual in Ubuntu 16.04.

Proofs:

```
/lib/systemd/system# grep root *
grep: invalid option -- '.'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

/lib/systemd/system# grep root .
grep: .: Is a directory
```

It only works in this way.

```
/lib/systemd/system# grep root ./*
[...]
```

Has changed something in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: If you're using zsh, hitting tab at the end of your command will expand `*` out into its arguments immediately, so you can see what you're actually running.  Or, using bash, you can make use of a special mode that will echo out every command before running it (this is useful when debugging shell scripts as well) via `set -x ; grep root * ; set +x` .

Answer (score 13):

> ```
> /lib/systemd/system# grep root *
> grep: invalid option -- '.'
> Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
> Try 'grep --help' for more information
> ```

Looks like you have a file named `-.`. You can get around this by delimiting the filenames from the options with `--`, e.g.:

```
grep root -- *
```

> ```
> /lib/systemd/system# grep root .
> grep: .: Is a directory
> ```

`grep` doesn't recurse by default, use `-R`:

```
grep -R root .
```

Using just `-R` without a directory is fine (`grep` assumes current directory):

```
grep -R root
```

Comment: Worth noting that this `--` trick works on most command line programs, where any argument following `--` is treated as positional even if it would be otherwise interpreted as an optional argument. Another option is to put the file in quotes, e.g. `grep root '-.'` but this won't work with wildcards of course

Comment: @Thomas putting `-.` in quotes won't help, since quotes affect shell processing and this is a problem with grep's argument processing. You can do something like `./-.`

Comment: You were right! there is a file called "-.slice"

How did you figure out that?

Comment: @Francisco, from knowing that the `*` glob causes problems when you have filenames that look like options and the error message claiming an option named "." (i.e. "-.") was used.